# Handling options in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been maintaining a Firefox extension for years now and started in on a Chrome port.

So I've seen the storage apis (localStorage & chrome.storage) and they work and all, but how am I suppose to do default preferences?

localStorage is kinda useless, because you get a separate copy for each and every web page, and my extension runs inside web pages.

The chrome.storage api exists, but aside from the headaches caused by it being asynchronous there's no easy way to set defaults :(.

Basically I want to be able to call set and have it only set the value if it doesn't already exists.

I guess I could do a get for all the values and then a set for the ones that don't have values, but that gets real clumsy real fast.

It just feels like I'm making this too hard. Does anyone have any advise on handling preferences in a Chrome extension?

Comment: Have you already seen the topic on Options pages in the documentation? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options

Answer (score 1):

You have ~2 options:

Either call `chrome.storage.get({'key1': 'default1', 'key2': 'default2'}, callback)` to provide the defaults each time you read a value from storage, as described in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options#step_2), or set up your defaults in your extension's [`onInstalled`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) event:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled(function(details) {
  chrome.storage.get({
    'key1': 'default1',
    'key2': 'default2'
  }, function(options_with_defaults) {
    chrome.storage.set(options_with_defaults);
  });
});
```

You need to run the `get` first because `onInstalled` runs on upgrades in addition to initial installs, and you don't want to overwrite your users’ settings every time they upgrade.

The second option has a short race condition in that it'll overwrite any settings the user changes between the calls to `get()` and `set()`, but the code to prevent that is significantly more complex and probably not worth it. :-/

(To deal with the asynchrony headaches, I'd suggest wrapping `chrome.storage` into a [Promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)-based API. We'll do this eventually inside Chrome, but it'll take longer.)

Comment: Thanks I was afraid of that. :P, The Promises thing is new to me though :D. That looks like it'll help me clean up my code.